# Which Ubuntu to use for Dell N5110

Tags: dell

I have Dell N5110 laptop. It has 6gb of RAM, i5-2450M processor and GeForce GT525M graphic card. I wanted to ask, which version of Ubuntu would be best suited for this laptop? I installed 12.04 but the battery isn't lasting as long as it is on Windows 7. And also the fan is noisier than on Windows. But the CPU temperature is sligtly higher than on Windows.

On Windows ~ 52 - 55 degrees celsius. 
On Ubuntu 12.04 ~ 59 - 65 degrees celsius.

Which version would you recoment to change to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your ubuntu to latest version 12.04.1

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't specific enough. I have 12.04.1 . And I have installed sensors to detect CPU temperature. It shows ~ 65 and more degrees

Comment: check this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks